# ¿Como deberia definir una expresion regular para obtener los numeros del mes y del año de una fecha en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python, flask

Desearia obtener los dos numeros que corresponden al mes de una fecha en formato dd-mm-aaaa usando MySQL.

Hasta ahora esto:

```
^\w{2}-("+month+")-+("+year+")$
```

Usando Python intercambio month y year por las variables correpondientes, quedando por ejemplo

```
^\w{2}-(11)-+(2018)$
```

Usando un test online de RegExp(https://www.regextester.com/)

Al probar las fechas `01/11/2018`, `05/11/2017`, la primera sale como valida para esa expresión regular, por tener el mes y el año buscado.

Al usarla en MySQL mediante PHPMyAdmin, arroja esto:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `date` REGEXP '^\\w{2}-(11)-+(2018)$'
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 seconds.)
```

Los datos de `date` son estos: `01/11/2018` y `05/10/2018`

*El formato de date es dd/mm/aaaa y es un string de 10 caracteres*

En python lo obtengo asi:

```
datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
// 01/11/2018
```

**¿Como puedo configurar esta expresión regular para que me funcione correctamente?**

### Datos Adicionales:

Actualmente estoy guardando las fechas en dicho formato utilizando un campo varchar.

Para mi aplicacion uso `Flask-SQLAlchemy` (extension ORM de Flask, microframework de Python).

Entonces al hacer la query debo utilizar lo siguiente:

```
jobs = Job.query.filter(job.date.op("regexp")(regexp))
```

Donde:

**Job:** es la clase que representa a la tabla Job.

**Filter:** actua como un where

**op("regexp")** ejecuta una expresión regular

Comment: Los datos de date, son del tipo date?

Comment: ¿Por qué expresión regular? ¿La columna no es del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`? Con hacer algo como `SELECT MONTH(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year`  ya lo tienes. Y si son `VARCHAR` puedes convertir a fecha y aplicar las funciones `MONTH` y  `YEAR`

Comment: @A.Cedano o en el peor de los casos, tomar los valores entre las / del string ;)

Comment: Correcto @gbianchi. Usar expresiones regulares para esto es como coger un avión para ir al barrio de al lado. Exagero un poco, pero hay que saber que las expresiones regulares tienen su costo y no hay que usarlas para cosas sencillas.

Comment: prueba eso en el where: MONTH(fecha)= numero
Donde fecha es la fecha almacenada y numero el mes a comparar

Comment: @A.Cedano y como convertiria a fecha ese valor?.

Comment: ¿No es del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`?  Si no lo es, di de qué tipo es y qué formato tiene. Y... si no lo es, deberías considerar una normalización de la tabla, si estuviera en tus manos.

Comment: @A.Cedano es un varchar de formato dd/mm/aaaa

Comment: @A.Cedano supongo deberia pasarla a aaaa-mm-dd para poder usar month y year

Comment: Puedes hacer esto directamente: **`SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y')) month, YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y')) year ;`**. Una prueba *a mano*: `SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('31-10-2018', '%d-%m-%Y')) month, YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('31-10-2018', '%d-%m-%Y')) year ;`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85207/discussion-between-victor-alvarado-and-a-cedano).

Comment: @gbianchi me funciono esa query de SELECT MONTH(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema recurri a lo siguiente:

1) Cambiar el formato del dato guardado, con el fin de que MySQL lo reconociera como una fecha.

De dd/mm/aaaa a aaaa-mm-dd

2) Seguido aplique lo sugerido por gbianchi:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year
```

3) En el caso de sqlalchemy utilice extract, el cual actuara como la funcion MONTH y YEAR

```
 filter(extract('year', MI_TABLA.date) == year)
 filter(extract("month", Mi_TABLA.date) == month)
```